# MVC method not receiving json array as List

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My MVC method is receiving the rest of my model, but not my list

javascript:

```
var userSettings = [ { Name: "SettingName", Value: "SettingValue" }, { Name: "SettingName1", Value: "SettingValue2" }];

var data = {
    Email: "thing@what.com",
    Password: "123",
    ConfirmPassword: "123",
    UserSettings: JSON.stringify(userSettings)
}

$.ajax({
    url: this.action,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(data)

})
```

C#/MVC

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUser model)
{
    //stuff
}

public class CreateUser
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    public List<NameValue> UserSettings { get; set; }
}

public class NameValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing here? How come my UserSettings always comes through empty?

If I change UserSettings to String instead of List it receives the json string, but I can't get it to receive it as a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't stringify `userSettings`.

Doing so will create strings with escaped quotes and MVC won't know how to bind it.

With stringify:

```
"{"Email":"thing@what.com","Password":"123","ConfirmPassword":"123","UserSettings":"[{\"Name\":\"SettingName\",\"Value\":\"SettingValue\"},{\"Name\":\"SettingName1\",\"Value\":\"SettingValue2\"}]"}"
```

Without stringify:

```
"{"Email":"thing@what.com","Password":"123","ConfirmPassword":"123","UserSettings":[{"Name":"SettingName","Value":"SettingValue"},{"Name":"SettingName1","Value":"SettingValue2"}]}"
```

Your code should look like:

```
var data = {
    Email: "thing@what.com",
    Password: "123",
    ConfirmPassword: "123",
    UserSettings: userSettings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are JSON stringifying the settings twice, once in the data object, and again in the AJAX call.

Try:

```
UserSettings: userSettings
```

For working with JSON data, I find Fiddler to be an immense help in finding serialization problems.